# Buildroot genimage error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: pi-1, buildroot

I am trying to update my RPi-1 buildroot image that has been working fine for more than a year now
(I want to add GPIO packages).

I am using WSL on Windows 10 and I made a fresh clone from git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot

Build works, and I can see the output files in the images/ dir.

However, I am seeing the following error when generating the sdcard.img image:

```
>>>   Executing post-image script board/raspberrypi/post-image.sh
board/raspberrypi/genimage-raspberrypi.cfg:33: no sub-section title/index for 'config'
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "rm -rf "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp"/*" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "cp -a "/tmp/tmp.MCWDYwbxZH" "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp/root"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "find '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp/root' -depth -type d -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 -I {} touch -r '/tmp/tmp.MCWDYwbxZH/{}' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/build/genimage.tmp/root/{}'" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images"" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "dd if=/dev/zero of="/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat" seek=33554432 count=0 bs=1 2>/dev/null" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "mkdosfs   '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb' as 'bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb' as 'bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb' as 'bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin' as 'rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt' as 'rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'rpi-firmware/config.txt' as 'rpi-firmware/config.txt' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/rpi-firmware/config.txt' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'rpi-firmware/fixup.dat' as 'rpi-firmware/fixup.dat' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/rpi-firmware/fixup.dat' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'rpi-firmware/start.elf' as 'rpi-firmware/start.elf' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/rpi-firmware/start.elf' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'zImage' as 'zImage' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/zImage' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: hdimage(sdcard.img): adding partition 'boot' (in MBR) from 'boot.vfat' ...
ERROR: hdimage(sdcard.img): fiemap /home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/boot.vfat: 25 Inappropriate ioctl for device
ERROR: hdimage(sdcard.img): failed to write image partition 'boot'
INFO: hdimage(sdcard.img): cmd: "rm -f "/home/user0/repos/buildroot/output/images/sdcard.img"" (stderr):
ERROR: hdimage(sdcard.img): failed to generate sdcard.img
Makefile:833: recipe for target 'target-post-image' failed
make: *** [target-post-image] Error 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.